# In ZF the following holds: if there is an injection from $\omega$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$, then there is a surjection from $X$ to $\omega$.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am trying to understand the proof that the following holds in ZF: if there is an injection from $\omega$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$, then there is a surjection from $X$ to $\omega$.

I am reading the proof in Herrlich's Axiom of Choice, p.47.

I understand why the proof boils down to recursively defining $g: \omega \to \mathcal{P}(X)$, such that the $g(n)$'s are non-empty and pairwise disjoint.

I transcribe the proof below adding markers (1) and (2) for the points that are unclear to me.

**(1)** How can we be sure $n^\star$ exists?

**(2)** Is this supposed to be $g(n)=(X\setminus f(n^\star))\setminus \cup_{m<n} g(m)$? If not, how can we be sure we satisfy the pairwise disjoint requirement?

Let $f: \omega \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ be an injection. Define recursively a map $g: \omega \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that the $g(n)$'s are non void and pairwise disjoint: For $n\in \omega$, assume that the $g(m)$'s are defined for all $m<n$ such that the set $\{ f(k) \setminus \cup_{m<n} g(m): k \geq n \}$ is infinite.

Define **(1)**

$n^\star = min \{ k \, | \, k \geq n  \text{ and }  f(k) \setminus \cup_{m<n} g(m) \neq \emptyset \neq \big(X \setminus f(k)\big) \setminus \cup_{m<n} g(m) \}$

In case  $\{ f(k) \setminus \big(f(n^\star) \bigcup \cup_{m<n} g(m)\big) \, | \, k \geq n^\star \} $ is infinite, define $g(n)=f(n^\star) \setminus \cup_{m<n} g(m)$.

Otherwise, define **(2)** $g(n)=X \setminus \big( f(n^\star) \setminus \cup_{m<n} g(m) \big).$

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but here's an alternate proof you may find more intuitive. Let $g:\omega\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)$ be injective. For $x\in X$ let the **type** of $x$ be the set $$tp(x)=\{i: x\in g(i)\},$$ and let $$T=\{tp(x):x\in X\}.$$ We have $T\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\omega)$, and by injectivity of $f$ it's easy to see that $T$ is infinite; it's now a good exercise to show that any infinite subset of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ surjects onto $\omega$, and we can lift this to a surjection $X\rightarrow\omega$ by "factoring through" the map $x\mapsto tp(x)$.

Comment: @Noah Thank you!